# Elementary inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance

So I have a `Superclass` and two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` that extend `Superclass`.
`ClassA` and `Superclass` contain a method `.doSomething()`, `ClassB` does not.
I got instances of ClassA and -B in a `List<Superclass> objects`. There also is a loop that iterates through `objects` and calls `.doSomething()` like this:

```
for(Superclass o : objects){
    o.doSomething();
}
```

My question is: If `o` is an instance if `ClassA`, is then `ClassA.doSomething()` being called or does this loop only call `Superclass.doSomething()`?

Comment: If there was only a possibility to _simply try it_. Hint: `ClassA.doSomething()` is called.

Comment: The overriden version will always be the one that's used, so yes, it'll be `ClassA.doSomething()`

Comment: without seeing the code of ClassA, we cannot answer.

Comment: @davidxxx We cannot? What are you thinking of?

Comment: @Marvin 1. we don't know whether `doSomething()` is actually overrided in `ClassA`. 2. If it is, we don't know whether the implementation also invokes the method of the super class.

Comment: @davidxxx 1. *"ClassA and Superclass contain a method .doSomething()"*, this statement tells us that `ClassA` has `doSomething` and it is therefore an overrode. 2. This is a valid point. Although, the question title should indicate that this corner case is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: #1 is IMHO clearly stated in the question and #2 doesn't change the fact that the loop does **not** _"only call `Superclass.doSomething()`"_.

Comment: Your code will not even compile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because SuperClass implements doSomething, ClassB inherits that implementation,  ClassA overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the method `.doSomething()` of `ClassA` overrides the one of `Superclass`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Super
{
 void hi()
 {
 System.out.println("Super class");
 }
}
class A extends Super
{
 void hi()
 {
  System.out.println("Class A");
 }

}
class B extends Super
{


}
public class Drive
{

public static void main(String[]args)
{
 Super s=new A(); 
 s.hi();                // prints "Class A"
 Super h=new B();
 h.hi();             // prints "Super Class" since B does not override Super
}
}                        //hope this helps
```

Answer (score 0):

If an instance is of `ClassA`, then its method will be called, and superclass methods will only be consireded if `ClassA` doesn't have an implementation.

And this doesn't change if you assign the `ClassA` instance to a variable of a superclass type. In other languages, that might be different, but with Java it's always like that.